# Deleting input shapefile after being used in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a shapefile that is being used as an input into the start of a model. The model is very simple but makes up a much larger model.

The input is reprojected in the first step but is not needed ever again. Is there a way I can simply delete that shapefile permanently from my computer within the modeler itself?

Comment: How is your input shapefile selected? Do you select it from the drop-down list (i.e. it is already loaded into QGIS) or do you select it using the File Dialog?

Comment: Yes I select it from the drop-down list as it is already loaded into the QGIS project.

Comment: Then as far as I know there is no way to delete the file with your model. Tried that myself and could not find a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to this currently is to write a **custom script** which removes the layer from the table of contents and then deletes the shapefile.

You can create one from:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Then use something like the following:

```
##Example=name
##Layer_to_delete=vector

from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorFileWriter

layer = processing.getObject(Layer_to_delete)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer.id())
QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(layer.source())
```

---

Save the script into your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts` directory. Then add the custom script from the list of algorithms to your model, select, the input layer as the `Layer to delete` and set the *Reproject layer* tool as the **parent algorithm** (the script will run when the tool has finished):

[image: Example model]

---

When you run the model, once the *Reproject layer* tool has finished, the selected input layer should be removed from the interface and deleted (**make sure to keep backups!**)

Comment: I have tried running the model as described but when it gets to the script it crashes QGIS. I am not really sure why.

Comment: My coding is very poor so am I right or wrong in thinking that the script you described should work as it is as long as I have correctly linked the input layer and set the reproject layer tool as the parent algorithm?

Comment: I have noticed that when running the script on its own it doesn't work. However if I remove the line: QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(layer.source()) then it runs fine and removes the map layer.

Comment: @AGW94 - Which QGIS version and platform are you using? I used QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit. Do you receive any error messages when QGIS crashes?

Comment: I am using 2.18.13 LTR on Windows Server 2012 R2 at my business. No I don't receive any error messages.

Comment: @AGW94 - I just tested on 2.18.13 and the model and script above works fine. Does QGIS crash with the same shapefile? Could you create a simple one and test it?