# Deleting input vector or raster being used in QGIS 3 modeler

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

As it is explained in the title I am writing a script to process this task.

The script is already written but I need it to be triggered when the inputs are not needed anymore. In other words : I need to set the parents algorithms box in my script. Like in the illustration below :

[image: illustration]

Illustration comes [from this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257602/deleting-input-shapefile-after-being-used-in-qgis-modeler?).

It seems for the "processing.run" method we can set that with the `is_child_algorithm=TRUE` parameter?

But I use "pure" Python in my script so it doesn't matches.

I can't find the method for my case in QGIS documentation.

Does anyone has the corresponding code for this case ?